# How can I debug Cisco Anyconnect constantly connecting and reconnecting?

Tags: vpn, connection, cisco, client

I was using Cisco Anyconnect just fine until couple of days ago. But now, it keeps constantly connecting and then reconnecting in cycles of a few seconds, making it completely useless. I know this is not an issue with the server because I tested the connection on a Win machine and it worked just fine.

So, being new to ubuntu, what are the steps to debug this issue?

**Update 1:**

Using the suggestion by @waltinator, I see the following. This is the portion between making the connection and then getting reconnecting message.

```
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnui[13564]: Message type information sent to the user: Connected to x US Global Remote Access.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: internalReadSocket File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/UdpTcpTransports_unix.cpp Line: 507 Invoked Function: ::read Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: callbackHandler File: ../../vpn/Common/IPC/SocketTransport.cpp Line: 1861 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::internalReadSocket Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: OnSocketReadComplete File: ../../vpn/Agent/TlsProtocol.cpp Line: 806 Invoked Function: CSocketTransport::readSocket Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: OnTunnelReadComplete File: ../../vpn/Agent/CstpProtocol.cpp Line: 1466 Invoked Function: CSslProtocol::OnTunnelReadComplete Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: OnTunnelReadComplete File: ../../vpn/Agent/TunnelStateMgr.cpp Line: 1581 Invoked Function: Read tunnel callback status Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. SSL
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: OnTunnelReadComplete File: ../../vpn/Agent/TlsTunnelMgr.cpp Line: 1891 Invoked Function: CTunnelStateMgr::readTunnel Return Code: -31588336 (0xFE1E0010) Description: SOCKETTRANSPORT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_SHUTDOWN:The socket was shutdown by the operating system or a remote peer. callback
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: The Primary SSL connection to the secure gateway is being re-established.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: Function: OnTunnelStateChange File: ../../vpn/Agent/TND.cpp Line: 2030 tunnel state change notification (new 1, old 1)
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: The VPN client has sent the following close message to the gateway: Reconnecting to recover from error.
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnagent[1339]: A SSL Alert was sent by the client during a write operation.  Severity: warning Description: close notify
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnui[13564]: VPN state: Reconnecting Network state: Network Accessible Network control state: Network Access: Restricted Network type: Undefined
Apr 02 22:15:58 s-ThinkPad-X230 acvpnui[13564]: Message type information sent to the user: Reconnecting to x US Global Remote Access...
```

Any clue what could be the issue?

Comment: To debug traffic I suggest wireshark. Is your connection wired or wireless?

Comment: I can do both. And I have tried both with no success.

Comment: Begin by looking at `journalctl --follow`

Comment: Thanks, @waltinator. I updated my question with what I got. Any idea?